# Displaying dynamic images based on an Int value (for showing player's score on main menu) – JAVA/XML/Android/Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, image, sharedpreferences

**Disclaimer**: I’m extremely new to Java/Xml, so please bear with me. I’m using Replica Island source so if there’s an easier/newer way of doing this, please let me know.

**Objective**: Display a player’s score on the main menu screen using .PNG numbers instead of text. Why? Because my .PNG numbers are much more flashy/stylized than standard text.

**Currently**: I’m capturing and displaying the player’s score via an int variable that’s saved to and loaded from in *SharedPreferences*. I’m then displaying it TEXT via the following:

**Current XML**:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"  
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:textSize="24sp"
android:textColor= "#FF0000"
android:background="#99000000" 
/>
```

**Current MainMenuActivity Class:**

```
int mHighScoreCoin = 
    prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.PREFERENCE_COINS_COLLECTED, 0);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Current High Score: " + mHighScoreCoin);
```

This works fine, but I don’t want basic text on my main menu. During actual gameplay, I’m using the following method to convert my int score, into an array that calls my .PNG numbers (0-9) to display them in game:

```
public int intToDigitArray(int value, int[] digits) {
    int characterCount = 1;

    if (value >= 1000) {characterCount = 4;} 
    else if (value >= 100) {characterCount = 3;} 
    else if (value >= 10) {characterCount = 2;}

    int remainingValue = value;
    int count = 0;

    do {
        int index = remainingValue != 0 ? remainingValue % 10 : 0;
        remainingValue /= 10;
        digits[characterCount - 1 - count] = index;
        count++;
        } 
    while (remainingValue > 0 && count < digits.length);            

    if (count < digits.length) {digits[count] = -1;}           
        return characterCount;
    }
```

Question: How can I display the high score in my XML/MainmenuActivity class, using the .PNG version of the numbers instead of the text I’m currently using?

**The start of my feeble Attempt:**

```
…
mdrawScore = findViewById(R.id.drawScore);
…
if(mdrawScore !=null){
    HudSystem hud = new HudSystem();
    int[] mCoinDigitsForMenu;
    mCoinDigitsForMenu = new int[4];
    hud.intToDigitArray(mHighScoreCoin, mCoinDigitsForMenu);
}
```

Note: This question may be unanswerable with the information provided. Again, I’m extremely new to Java and in over my head.   For example, do I need to be pulling a ton more stuff from “HudSystem” to finish creating the array of images?

Any details or general thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wwwhhhhelp, after hours and hours of reading (thanks Stack Overflow!) and trial and error, I've answered my own question.

Is it the cleanest, most effective approach?  HIGHLY unlikely (again, I have almost no idea wtf i'm doing, lol). Regardless, it works, :).  I tweaked it further but here's the general concept.

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/mainSectionMenu"
    >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/drawScore"
        android:layout_width="70dp" 
        android:layout_height="70dp" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/drawScore2"
        android:layout_width="70dp" 
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/drawScore3"
        android:layout_width="70dp" 
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-9dp"
        android:clickable="false" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

**MainMenuActivity**

After pulling the players mHighScoreCoin from SharedPreferences (onCreate AND onResume), I run the following:

```
    if(mHighScoreCoin >99){
        int HundsDigit = mHighScoreCoin/100;
        ImageView imageviewHunds = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawScore);
        int hunds = HundsDigit;
        String.valueOf(hunds);
        int resIdHunds = getResources().getIdentifier("ui_" + String.valueOf(hunds), "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageviewHunds.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resIdHunds));

        int tensDigit = ((mHighScoreCoin / 10)%10);
        ImageView imageviewTens = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawScore2);
        int tens = tensDigit;
        String.valueOf(tens);
        int resIdTens = getResources().getIdentifier("ui_" + String.valueOf(tens), "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageviewTens.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resIdTens));

        int onesDigit = (mHighScoreCoin % 10);
        ImageView imageviewOnes = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawScore3);
        int ones = onesDigit;
        String.valueOf(ones);
        int resIdOnes = getResources().getIdentifier("ui_" + String.valueOf(ones), "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageviewOnes.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resIdOnes));

    }
    else if(mHighScoreCoin > 9)
    {
        int tensDigit = mHighScoreCoin/10;
        ImageView imageviewTens = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawScore);
        int tens = tensDigit;
        String.valueOf(tens);
        int resIdTens = getResources().getIdentifier("ui_" + String.valueOf(tens), "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageviewTens.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resIdTens));

        int onesDigit = (mHighScoreCoin % 10);
        ImageView imageviewOnes = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawScore2);
        int ones = onesDigit;
        String.valueOf(ones);
        int resIdOnes = getResources().getIdentifier("ui_" + String.valueOf(ones), "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageviewOnes.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resIdOnes));

    }
    else {
        ImageView imageviewOnes = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawScore2);
        int ones = mHighScoreCoin;
        String.valueOf(ones);
        int resIdOnes = getResources().getIdentifier("ui_" + String.valueOf(ones), "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageviewOnes.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resIdOnes));
    }
```